# Django DateTimeField with timezone information

Tags: python, django, postgresql, datetime, timezone

I have a Django model with a DateTimeField with a postgres 9.3 database as backend.

```
measure_datetime = models.DateTimeField()
```

In my Database this created a column like this

```
ALTER TABLE geoudis_weathermeasurements ADD COLUMN measure_datetime timestamp with time zone;
```

of type

```
timestamp with time zone
```

As you can see it stores datetime with timezone. I inserted the data with a different tool. And when I do a simple query like that

```
SELECT measure_datetime from geoudis_weathermeasurements where "id" = 44525
"2014-10-01 00:04:54+02"
```

This looks good. Now I query the data from within Django and this returns for the same row a Datetime object with UTC timezone

```
2014-09-30 22:04:54+00:00 
tzinfo=UTC
_utcoffset=0:00:00
```

So it looks like the original timezone information is gone. Of course I could set it to a different timezone but what if I don't know in which timezone the data was measured? Server to display the data can be in a different timezone. Therefor I thought this postgres datatype (timezone with timestamp) is good for.

Am I doing something wrong here? Thanks for any help or suggestions.

EDIT1:

If I set **USE_TZ = False** in settings.py I get the result I want.
It seems to me this behavior is intended by django.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Django at all, but I can tell you that if you don't know in which timezone (UTC offset) the data was measured, then you don`t know the time!

Here are your options:

1. **Make sure you work only with UTC** (or with one UTC offset). That's best, but you can't always choose what you get.
2. **Work only with local time.** That's really troublesome (computer changes location, user changes time zone settings, daylight saving time switches, ...).